# Selective assignment of values to parameters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I learn JavaScript. I used C# before and I expected some C#-similar behaviour for this function:

```js
function foo(a = 'asdf', b = 3.5, c = true) {
  return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
}
console.log(foo());
console.log(foo('qwerty', 123, false));
console.log(foo(b = 567));
console.log(foo(c = true, a = 'qwerty', b = 789));
// console.log(foo(,55,)); // gives VM806:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,
```

I marked the output results which surprised me:

[image]

Hm... Is it mean that it is impossible to point parameter values selectively and it is impossible to replace the parameters positions even if their names was pointed obviously?

I tried to find the answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/default_parameters) but I found nothing.

Comment: You are not calling the function and naming the parameters, you are assigning a value to *a* variable and are calling the function with that. If you put console.log(a) underneath the last call, you'd see `qwerty`. The call would still have worked if you use `foo(bar='aaa')`

Comment: @mplungjan, I added now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have named function parameters like C# and Python. Your function definition just provides default values for each parameter, but the arguments are matches with parameters by their position.

You can get something similar using ES6 destructuring, by passing the parameters in an object.

```js
function foo({a = 'asdf', b = 3.5, c = true} = {}) {
  return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
}

console.log(foo());
console.log(foo({a: 'qwerty', b: 123, c: false}));
console.log(foo({b: 567}));
console.log(foo({c: true, a: 'qwerty', b: 789}));
```

I added `= {}` to the function definition to allow calling the function with no arguments; otherwise the first call would have to be `foo({})`

Answer (score 0):

you are just referencing the value to be passed as the parameter when u are calling the function

```
         function foo(a = 'asdf', b = 3.5, c = true){
            return a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c;
         }
         foo() => asdf 3.5 true  

         foo(b ='google') => a 3.5 true // in this case u are declaring a variable b with value 'google' and passing to your function and in your function the reference parameter is 'a' (so the variable 'b' is assigned to 'a' and the value of b is google its like a=b='google') so the final value of parameter a is 'google'

         var name = 'google';

         foo(name) => google 3.5 true
```